# Typescript: Allow generic type but not it's subtype

Tags: typescript, generics, types, typescript-generics

F.e. I want to allow any **object** but not exact instance of some subtype
The code below doesn't give me any warns and successfully compiles.

```
type Non<N, T> = T extends N ? never : T;

const a: Non<Error, object> = new Error(); // Should get type error
```

Comment: `typeof new Error === "object"`

Comment: Yeah, but why it doen't fail on a first check and is being resolved to object again and not to never. How can I achieve something like that

Comment: `Error` extends `object`. `object` does not extend `Error`. `T` extends `N` means that any `T` value is assignable to a variable of type `N`.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't use `object`. Instead use either the `Record<>` type or the `any` type.

Comment: However it doesn't help event if I use Record

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your type **does** work, just not in the way that you're using it.

When you use the type hint `const a: Non<Error, object>`, the type only gets evaluated once and it's evaluated with the specific values that you provided it: `N = Error` and `T = object`.

```
type Non<Error, object> 
   = object extends Error ? never : object
   = false ? never : object
   = object
```

In other words, `Non<Error, object>` just equals `object`.  Always.  That's because there are no variables here, we are just comparing the type `object` and the type `Error`.

Here's an example of a usage where your `Non` type makes sense, using it as the assertion on a [type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guardsv).

```
const isNotError = <T>(value: T): value is Non<Error, T> => {
    return ! (value instanceof Error)
}

const checkVal = (value: Error | {s: string} ): string => {
    if ( isNotError( value ) ) {
        // value cannot be of type Error
        return value.s;
    } else {
        // value must be of type Error
        return value.message;
    }
}
```

FYI what you are writing here is already a built-in type called [`Exclude`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion).  `Exclude` puts the arguments in the opposite order of your `Non` type, so thing that you are excluding goes second.